# In Django, how to pass the input from user to the url of next page?

Tags: django, url, request

In my Django project, I have two webpages.User input data in the first webpage, and then the second webpage provides the user something that is selected by user's input in the first webpage.

But I do not know how to pass the input from the user in the first webpage to the view function of the second webpage.

Here is my view.py which include the code for the first webpage:

```
class MajorProgramForm(forms.Form):
    major_programs = forms.ChoiceField(label='Major Programs', choices=MAJORS, required=True)

def choose_major_program(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = MajorProgramForm(request.GET)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "program.html", context)）
```

Here is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', choose_major_program, name="choose_major_program")]
```

And below is my template for the first webpage:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Choose Major Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Choose Major Program</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="frame"> 
            <form name="form" action="{% url 'choose_major_program' %}" method="GET">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <ul>
            <select name="major_choice">
            {% for value, text in form.major_programs.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't work is a downvote magnet here in stackoverflow. Never use that phrase. Always explain what happened and also show what exactly you tried

Answer (score 0):

```
def second_website(request):
    request.GET['major_choice'] # Gets the value of the parameter on the URL
```

But first, modify the form's action argument to send the data to the second template

```
<form name="form" action="{% url 'second_website' %}" method="GET">
```

Comment: After select "french" and click submit button on the first webpage, the url of the first page become as below, which I think is wrong: http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=arno5N9jmnKF95J3RdQCuoG3UnBQnFyP0w8aEBZHYOFFKIyiurGR8yoyW2dud9qA&major_choice=bs+in+environmental+science+MAJOR                                                                                                        So how to pass the request.GET to the url of the first page?

Comment: And I have another problem. My second will provide users some choices. Therefore, in my second form, I need choices. If I use request.GET['major_choice'], how to give the second form choices?

Comment: Can you post the content of the MAJORS iterable variable? The one you reference in your MajorProgramForm